# Styling a parent element according child state

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="main-div">
op: <input type="checkbox" id="ck">
</div>
```

Is there a way to style "main-div" according to "ck" state, ONLY using CSS? For example, if "ck" is checked "main-div" should apply a yellow background.

Using pseudo-class : using checked, it's possible to verify ck state, but how would it target the main-div?

Comment: There is no parent selector is CSS.

Comment: @j08691 http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#has-pseudo

Comment: @user3790069 - That's a draft of a spec that's not implemented yet.

Comment: @user3790069 Do you know how is current browser support for has-pseudo?

Comment: @Borachio I tried `:has` in Chrome 37 and Firefox 32, unfortunately, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

No, there is currently no way.
See the accepted answere here for more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/3892957